# Broadcom BCM43224 wifi issue [14e4:4353] (rev01)

Tags: networking, wireless, 18.04, broadcom

I'm experiencing troubles with my Dell Studio 1747 laptop and wifi card BCM43224 [14e4:4353] (rev 01). I'm using Xubuntu 18.04, but also had the same on Ubuntu 17.10. I'm using broadcom-sta driver but with bcmwl-kernel-source and even with open source drivers it's the same.

In general wifi works, but from time to time (once every 3-4 boots in average) there is no wifi interface - as it is not recognized by system or drivers are not loading. I tried to find any link between this situation and the behavior of the system (installing packages, updates, etc.), but I can't see any. It seems to be completely random.

Below you can find listing of the results of several commands.

Results of `lspci` :

```
08:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Inc. and subsidiaries BCM43224 802.11a/b/g/n [14e4:4353] (rev 01)
```

Results of `lshw`

```
*-network UNCLAIMED  
                description: Network controller  
                product: BCM43224 802.11a/b/g/n  
                vendor: Broadcom Inc. and subsidiaries  
                physical id: 0  
                bus info: pci@0000:08:00.0  
                version: 01  
                width: 64 bits  
                clock: 33MHz  
                capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list  
                configuration: latency=0  
                resources: memory:f8000000-f8003fff
```

Results of `dmesg` :

```
[   21.184919] wl: loading out-of-tree module taints kernel.  
[   21.184925] wl: module license 'MIXED/Proprietary' taints kernel.  
[   21.187747] wl: module verification failed: signature and/or required key missing - tainting kernel  
[   21.191007] wl 0000:08:00.0: enabling device (0000 -> 0002)  
[   21.191196] wl driver 6.30.223.271 (r587334) failed with code 1  
[   21.191198] ERROR @wl_cfg80211_detach :   
[   21.191199] NULL ndev->ieee80211ptr, unable to deref wl  

/etc/modprobe.d/broadcom-sta-dkms.conf  
blacklist b43  
blacklist b43legacy  
blacklist b44  
blacklist bcma  
blacklist brcm80211  
blacklist brcmsmac  
blacklist ssb
```

If I try to load wl driver manually (with modprobe), nothing happens.

`rfkill list all` also gives no output.

Here is the link to successful and failed boot, as Michael suggested:
https://drive.google.com/open?id=1oFS-Cesn1RI2LoXB1m1MBZpTOrj82Fjp

Comment: Has the laptop ever been dropped? If so, and you know how to open it up without damaging anything, go in and make sure the wifi card header is clean and that it is completely pushed onto it's header. If not, then look at the logs even on good boots till it fails again then look for differences between last known good and most recent failed log.

Comment: No it hasn't been dropped, at least I do not know anything about it :) I did what you suggest and wifi is firmly placed in the header, and the header itself seems to be ok and clean. I suspect that the wifi card is ok since I did not have such issues some time ago once I used also Windows 7 from time to time.

Comment: Also link with dmes output after successful and failed boot  https://drive.google.com/open?id=1oFS-Cesn1RI2LoXB1m1MBZpTOrj82Fjp